# There is a issue connecting my linux mint to a wired connection

Tags: linux, networking, linux-mint

My system was perfectly connecting to a wired connection before. I went on a vacation and before i left, my system was up running and it was connected to the internet. But when i am back again, i could see the computer was turned off. When i turned it back on i could see that i am not able to connect back to my LAN connection. It is displaying a  message connecting to the wired network, but then after few minutes it shows disconnected.

this is my ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:c9:ef:d9:55:4b  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6c9:efff:fed9:554b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:42629 (42.6 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7c00000-f7c20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11541 (11.5 KB)  TX bytes:11541 (11.5 KB)
```

From answers from other forums i also checked

```
sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

The output is as follow:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet dhcp
```

It was suggested to Append this to the file and reboot:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

But, doing so changed the wired connections to unmannaged. Could anyone please find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Did you tried `sudo dhclient eth0`?

Comment: Check `sudo dmesg` when the disconnection appears

Comment: @GenaroMorales: I tried sudo dhcleint eth0, but still not able to connect

Comment: @user4759923: i got several lines of output. do you want to copy paste all of them?